# changing the background color & customizing search box of dataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables, jsp-tags

I've used dataTables for my table. But I want to give some new looks to the tables but do not know where to do them. My files are:

```
<link href="css/demo_page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/demo_table_jui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

My table has background color for the rows as white (for even) and light violet (for odd). I want to **change the color of the rows**, how can I do it?

Also I want to **write default text in the search box** as "Search via any field". Which of the files I have to edit for these changes?

Answer (score 0):

For table row colors changes the demo_table.css file under this comment:

```
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * DataTables row classes
 */
```

For a default text into the search box add this parameter to the initialization of the dataTable:

```
"oSearch": {"sSearch": "Search via any field"}
```